# RARP using Python standard libraries

Tags: python, ip

I have a few webcams whose MAC IDs are known. I need a way to determine the corresponding IP addresses. Assume everything is on the same wifi network. I, however, do not have privilege to modify the wifi network router settings (in other words, I cannot assign static IPs to the cams).

I have heard of Reverse-ARP protocol which can help identify the IP address given the MAC ID. [There is](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arp) a library available for ARP/RARP but I was wondering if this could be done without installing an external library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a raw socket and implement the protocol on your own. It should not be so complicated if you feel comfortable getting your hands dirty.
However I'm not sure that it would work as expected. It's quite old and probably unsupported.
Maybe you could rely con DHCP. But if you cannot mangle with the router, probably, the only thing left to do is an "ARP scan".

Comment: What is the "ARP scan"? Can I do ARP using standard libraries in Python?

Comment: It is simply a "bruteforce", you make ARP requests for every IP in the subnet (maybe asking first for IPs previously owned by your targets) until you find what you want. It is dirty and ugly, but I cannot think to anything better. However ARP protocol is not implemented in standard libs in python, but it is a fairly simple protocol, you may try implementing it on your own with struct and raw sockets. Here some links: [ARP specifications](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc826), [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: As a side note: when dealing with socket at low level [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is really useful, but I guess that you don't want to use external libraries.